# concatenate requirejs modules into single file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to concatenate all my requires modules and a few text templates into a single concatenated and uglified main.min.js, so I can include that file in my HTML.

I figured out concatenation and uglifying part. However, I am not able to actually run any code in the browser then.

I created a [bare-bone project on github](https://github.com/forste/requirejs-barebone), to reproduce the problem.

File structure:

- main.js
- index.html
- log.js
- build-production
- lib/require.js
- node_modules/require/bin/r.js

I concatenate main.js, log.js and require.js using the build file build-production:

```
./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o build-production.js
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        requireLib : 'lib/require/require'
    },
    waitSeconds: 1000
});

console.log('loading main.js');

define(function(require) {
    var log = require('log');
    console.log('loaded')

    log.fine('main loaded');
});
```

build-production.js:

```
({
    mainConfigFile : 'main.js',
    include : [ 'requireLib' ],
    name : 'main.js',
    out : 'main.min.js' })
```

index.html:

```
<script src="main.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so index.html in a browser should print out

> loading main.js
>   loaded
>   loaded main

but it only prints out the first line

> loading main.js

anybody knows, why that is the case?

Comment: You might need to define `paths: { requireLib : 'lib/require/require' }` in your build file. See [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics).

Comment: thanks @c24w. requireLib should be taken from my main.js as I specify `mainConfigFile : 'main.js'`. I tried it anyways. Didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just had a closer look at your code.

I'm not sure why you're loading in the minified file using:

```
<script src="main.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's still an [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) module, hence needs to be loaded in using an AMD loader (otherwise the `define` doesn't get handled).

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['main.min'], function () {
        require(['main'], function () {});
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** whilst the outer require loads in the minified file (containing all modules), you also need a second, nested require to load the actual module still known as *main*.

It's quite misleading having a single module named *main* and then a minified version of all modules named *main.min*.  For example, I might expect *main* to be exactly the same as *main.min*, but without any optimisations applied.  You may consider renaming to something like:

- entry-point: *myApp*
- compiled (`optimize: 'none'`): *main*
- compiled (`optimize: 'uglify2'`): *main.min*

**Edit 2:** in your build file:

`name: 'main.js'` → `name: 'main'`

That will make requirejs name that module *main* instead:

`define('main.js', ...);` → `define('main', ...);`

Now: `require(['main'])` finds (and loads) the module named *main* in the local scope of the compiled file.

Before: `require(['main'])` didn't find a module named *main* (it was named *main.js*) so treats it as a file name and loads `./main.js`.

**Edit 3:** alternatively to **Edit 2**, in your build file you could retain:

`name: 'main.js'`

and add a path alias to either the build config or the run-time config:

`paths: { 'main' : 'main.js' }`

(This random thought comes with no warranty.)

Comment: thanks @c24w. the solution you posted doesn't load the concatenated script but loads all modules separately. so in my chrome's web developer tools > Resources > Scripts you see that log.js and main.js get loaded. I want to load only one file containing all modules

Comment: thanks again. that work's almost perfectly. last thing left: the main module (main.js) gets loaded twice. once within the concatenated file myApp.js (earlier main.min.js) and once the module itself. only the module itself gets executed then loading any further modules from the myApp.js

Comment: Updated again - it's hard to remember all the little tweaks I make as I go! Requirejs can get messy pretty quickly :(

Comment: wow, thank you! that's quite a hack actually to rename main.js to main in the build file. the value of 'name' is used for two totally different purposes apparently. firstly, it's used to find the entry point of your application, i.e. the main file. but additionally, due to requirejs's lookup algorithm we can use it to load the module.

Comment: Yeah... I don't actually know the best way to get this sort of setup to work, but after much stress and reading of the sample config file, that was about the best I could manage!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I thought it would be useful for others, who might be looking for a similar solution. And I decided to post here for documentation purposes.

There is also [browserify](http://browserify.org/) that does exactly what you are looking for. Its use is similar to **require** (on npm) but you can use it on the browser side. I found it useful.